# Creating a Windows VM with Virtualbox

Tags: command-line, windows, virtualbox

Is there a way to create a Windows VM in Virtualbox ONLY using CLI?

Comment: What version of Windows do you want to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is entirely possible with an image of an existing Windows OS to use as the virtual disk. It would also be possible with a Windows installation disk/iso file. For either type of installation, you'll require the product keys for the OS. The `vboxmanage` commands are going to be your friends in this endeavour, [they're described here](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#idp55423424).

You'll be running your VM without a display, which is known as headless mode.

With the existing image installation, you basically restore the image to the virtual disk of the VM. With the iso/disk installation, you attach the iso file or host DVD drive as a DVD drive to the VM, and use the virtual disk as the target for the installation.

I've moved several physical installations of Windows XP, which we needed to continue to use for legacy development, onto headless VirtualBox VMs hosted on Ubuntu 14.04 servers.

At the OS installation stage, you're going to need to connect to the VM to interact with Windows, probably via RDP, which will require setting the VRDE port for your VM, or using the default port of 3389.

This is a fairly involved process, once you indicate which Windows version you want I can point you in the direction of some tutorials.